# TCP connection not established in windows - c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, tcp

Using windows 10, visual studio 2017.

I've been reading a lot of examples and spent countless hours on this and can't get it to work.
I want a program to act as client and server depending on some variables (to duplicate this block on two different computers).

```
bool IPTunnel::runBlock(void)
{
   int ready = inputSignals[0]->ready(); //int ready2 = inputTCPConnetion[0]->ready();
WSADATA wsaData;

   int iResult;

   iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
   if (iResult != 0) {
       printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
       return 1;
   }

   //server
   SOCKET sockfd, newsockfd;
   int portno;
   socklen_t clilen;
   char buffer[256];
   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
   int n;

   char sendbuf[15] = "this is a test";
   char recvbuf[256];
   int resul;




   // create a socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0)
       printf("\n ERROR opening socket");

   // clear address structure
   bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

   portno = 5500;

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;//inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

   //if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
   bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
   //   printf("\n ERROR on binding");

   listen(sockfd, 5);

   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);


   newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
   if (newsockfd < 0)
       printf("ERROR on accept");

   printf("server: got connection from %s port %d\n",inet_ntop(serv_addr.sin_family,
       &serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, buffer, clilen), portno);

   //client
   int socketId = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
   socklen_t addrSize = sizeof(serverAddr);
   bzero((char*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
   serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   serverAddr.sin_port = htons(8080);
   serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addrSize);

   resul = send(socketId, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
   if (resul == SOCKET_ERROR) {
       printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       closesocket(newsockfd);
       WSACleanup();
       return 1;
   }
   printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", resul);

   do{
       resul = recv(newsockfd, recvbuf, 256, 0);
       if (resul > 0)
           printf("Bytes received: %d\n", resul);
       else if (resul == 0)
           printf("Connection closed\n");
       else
           printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
   } while (resul > 0);


   bzero(buffer, 256);


   resul = recv(socketId, buffer, 256, 0);

   fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", "Response from server", resul);

   while (true) { Sleep(1000); }
   return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

> server: got connection from 0.0.0.0 port 5500
>
> connect failed: 10038

(i checked this error 10038 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2)

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Server got socket at `newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);` Why create another one? Did this socket connect: `connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addrSize);`? Hard to say. There is no check.

Comment: Unrelated: Save yourself some code by taking advantage of [Zero Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)

Comment: `10038` is `Socket operation on nonsocket.An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`  I don't see a whole lot of error checking in your code. Even in the cases where you do check for error, you just print it out and allow the program to continue instead of aborting.

Comment: @selbie so do you have a solution for this error 10038 in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resul = send(socketId, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
```

Using `strlen` in `send` is bad idea, are you sure that your string is null terminated and you don't want nulls to be sent?

```
int socketId = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

Should be `SOCKET`, not `int`.

```
connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addrSize);
```

did you check return value? Connecting to port 8080 while listening to another port?

Consider using [WSAConnectByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnectbynamea) instead, much easier than filling sockaddrs, IPv6 compatible.

Also, you need threads. A server must call accept() and this would block. recv()/send() are blocking functions.

Comment: Handle?? Shouldn't it be SOCKET? And can you be more specific on the threads part. I don't understand why this code is not working..

Comment: I should have read this answer before commenting. @Borbat it is `socketId` that is producing the send error. As Michael states, `connect(socketId, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr, addrSize);` is not being checked to ensure a connection is being made. But why do you need this socket? I'd expect you should be using the already accepted and connected `newsockfd`.

Comment: But even using the newsockfd, it doesn't connect :(

Comment: @Borbat `if (newsockfd < 0) printf("ERROR on accept");` seems to disagree unless you ommitted this error message from your output. It is possible, however, that the client side disconnected before you got a chance to send. By the way, if you want to print out who connected, use `cli_addr`, not `serv_addr`.

Comment: @user4581301 i meant the connect(...) the client doesn't even connect to the socket. what could it be?

Comment: Yes the correct is SOCKET (although equal to HANDLE). Edited.